# String and state variable concatenation

Tags: reactjs

I am creating url by concatenating constant string and state variables as follows :

```
var url={"http://localhost:3000/get-players/"+{this.state.city}+"/"+{this.state.sport}};
```

But I am getting error. Can someone tell me where am I making mistake.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: There should be a way to declare `this.state.city` and `this.state.sport` to be a *string* variable. That way you will be able to concatenate them.

Comment: Use template literals in the future, your life will be easier.

Comment: This doesn't look like correct javascript (redundant `{}`)... Maybe you can add a [mcve] of your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use ES6 templating, do it the old way but remove the extra brackets (`{}`) around the variables.

`var url = "http://localhost:3000/get-players/" + this.state.city + "/" + this.state.sport;`

Answer (score 2):

You're string concatenation is incorrect, you could use string interpolation like this:

```
var url = `http://localhost:3000/get-players/${this.state.city}/${this.state.sport}`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url={"http://localhost:3000/get-players/"+{this.state.city}+"/"+{this.state.sport}};
```

`{this.state.city}` - is not string.

1: Correct variant for ES5:
`var url="http://localhost:3000/get-players/" + this.state.city + "/" + this.state.sport;`

`this.state.city` and `this.state.sport` should be declared and should be a type of `string`.

2: Correct variant for ES6

```
var url=`http://localhost:3000/get-players/${this.state.city}/${this.state.sport}`;
```